# Rspec can't see json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

When I run my spec I get the following error:

```
1) TasksController#index returns incompleted tasks 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(json).to_have(1).tasks }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `json' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TasksController::Index::ReturnsIncompletedTasks:0x00000005df8018>
```

Here's the **spec**:

```
describe "#index" do
    let!(:task){ FactoryGirl.create(:task) }

    context 'returns incompleted tasks' do

      before do
        get 'index', user_id: user.id, format: :json
      end

      it { expect(json).to_have(1).tasks }

    end
  end
```

Here's my **controller**:

```
def index
  #Some stuff
  render json: tasks
end
```

Why is this so?

Comment: you're not defining the `json` variable anywhere.... what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. This is how you test for json response

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
expect {
    JSON.parse(response.body)
}.to_not raise_error
```

To use the actual content you first need to parse it

```
result = JSON(response.body)
expect(result.length).to eq(1)
```

Comment: But how can I check what content that particular json could have?